# Mootools Javascript slideshow freezes after browsing website

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, mootools

Hi I have been using Rokstories, a mootools javascript slideshow in Joomla, I am having a very odd problem with Rokstories in IE . I have uploaded a temp copy to my server to show everyone.

If you click on my link in IE , the page loads and Rokstories works as normal, sliding from left to right every few seconds......click one of the other menu links, then go back to the home page and Rokstories does something very odd, the dots move along to say that it is going between slides, but the actual slide stays put and dont move.

If you clear your cache and reload the page it works fine again until you browse to another menu item and come back, then the problem starts again.

I have tested this with IE8 and get the problem, I have also tried it in Chrome & Firefox and done see a problem.

http://www.key4design.co.uk/test/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I notice (apart from the Google Maps API key alert) is that IE throws an error:

```
Line: 989
Error: 'Cufon' is undefined
```

Looking on Chrome/Safari/Firefox all throw up 404 on cufon-yui.js & /plugins/system/Cufon/key4font_400-key4font_700-key4font_italic_400-key4font_600.font.js

Our experience has been the IE will sometimes fail when JS files aren't in cache when it expects them to be. You might want to fix those first.

Comment: Thanks for that, you at a legend !, that works perfectly now,I had specified the directory with an upper case letter, so thats why it wasnt showing, I coded bits of this in January last year so I will let myself off, as I have got better since then lol. strange how the smallest things make IE go crazy.

Comment: The google maps prob was causing it too, as when I turned the module off it works, so that will need updating on the working site.